# Create an HTML file wih PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to create an html file from a php file that will contain this code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What i have so far:

```
$qq = "/"";
$myfile = fopen("mlgtest.html", "w")or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<html>\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "<head>\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "<meta http-equiv=" + $qq + "refresh" + $qq + "content=" + $qq + "0; url="+ $qq + "http://example.com/" + $qq + ">/n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "</head\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "</html>\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

But it doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: What error message do you have ?

Comment: Please can you explain the purpose a little better. Also, you do realise that you can simply just write HTML as normal in a php file, just don't use the php tags around it. Then just encase the php in tags :) If you are wanting to generate a file, best to go with the new DOMDocument(); option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra double quote in `$qq = "/"";`. It should be `$qq = "/";`.

Also PHP use `.` for concatination and not `+`.

Why dont you simply use

```
$htmlContent = '<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>'
```

Comment: It should be double quotes coz else it gives me an error.

Comment: I think there should try after removing the extra double quote. I can see clearly in the question that the text color is opposite to what it should be. Red is black and black is red.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use fwrite($myfile, $txt); again and again. try this instead

```
<?php

$txt .= "<head>";
$txt .= "</head>";
$txt .= "<body>";
$txt .= "</body>";
$txt .= "</html>";

echo $txt;exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new HTML document like so:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); //Create new document with specified version number
echo $dom->saveHTML();        //Outputs the generated source code
?>
```

Adding elements:

```
<?php
$br = $dom->createElement('br'); //Create new <br> tag
$dom->appendChild($br); //Add the <br> tag to document
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$qq`

```
$myfile = fopen("mlgtest.html", "w")or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = "<html>\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            $txt = "<head>\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            $txt = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />/n'; // notice using ' not "
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            $txt = "</head>\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            $txt = "</html>\n";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row is wrong, and the concatenation of string in PHP is done with the dot (".")

```
$qq = "/";
$myfile = fopen("mlgtest.html", "w")or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<html>\n";
$txt .= "<head>\n";
$txt .= "<meta http-equiv=" . $qq . "refresh" . $qq . "content=" . $qq . "0; url=". $qq . "http://example.com/" . $qq . ">/n";
$txt .= "</head>\n";
$txt .= "</html>\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```